# Engrave working in Blender but not for 3D Print

Tags: mesh, 3d-printing

So I'm creating a D20 dice with engraved numbers to 3D print and the steps I found on a tutorial work perfectly for Blender, but when I put it into the program to send it to my printer the numbers are no longer engraved but coming out of the dice.
(The YouTube tutorial I used is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc3d0pM2fpo)

The steps I used:

1. Create text
2. Position where you want it
3. Object - Convert - Mesh
4. Go to Edit Mode - Vertex selection
5. Press A to select all vertices
6. Mesh - Merge - By Distance
7. Back to Object Mode
8. Add Modifier - Solidify - Thickness .2
9. Right Click - Shade Smooth
10. Data tab - Normals - Click Auto box
11. Select main object - Add Modifier - Boolean - Select Object
12. Hide number in Viewport

Comment: seems like you would have to apply the boolean modifier so the extracted meshes stay in the actual mesh.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Can you share a link to the youtube tutorial you are talking about?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie of course! Here is the tutorial I used https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc3d0pM2fpo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial is unfortunately not made to be working for 3D printing, there are important steps (or rather information) missing for that.

As @HarryMcKenzie already said in the comments, you might want to apply the modifier. However (I suppose you try to export the object in a format like STL) in the export settings usually the *Apply Modifiers* option is already checked by default, so this step shouldn't be necessary.

Your problem is, the *Selection Only* option is not checked by default. And this means, the STL file will contain both, the embossed object and the text object even though it is made invisible in Blender.

But it is still in the scene (which is useful if you want to make changes on the text or the *Boolean* modifier later), so it gets exported with the main object (and all other mesh objects if there are more in the scene) into the STL file. And since the STL can only hold a single object, all meshes will become visible and be joined into this one object.

So to only export the embossed object you will either have to apply the *Boolean* modifier and then delete all other objects in the scene - or to be less destructive, just select the embossed object and make sure that you have both *Include* > *Selection Only* and *Geometry* > *Apply Modifiers* enabled.

[image: export settings]

Comment: omg it was that simple?? xD LOL thank you!! Applying the boolean modifiers and then deleting the text was not something I realized I needed to do so that worked out perfectly! Thank you so much!